# Getting warning for casting list, Type safety: Unchecked cast from List, Is this wrong way of writing query?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am a getting yellow line under the line:

```
return (List<HealthEntity>) criteria.list();
```

in the following code samle. The warning says:

> Type safety: Unchecked cast from List to List

and suggests me to use @SupressWarnings 'unchecked' to the method.

```
public List<HealthEntity> findByCustomerIds(List<Long> customerId) {
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(getPersistentClass());
    criteria.add(Restrictions.in("customerId", customerId));
    if (customerId != null && !customerId.isEmpty()) {
        return (List<HealthEntity>) criteria.list();
    } else {
        return new ArrayList<>(1);
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way to return my list of entities or am I making any mistake? Should I just use @SuppressWarnings?

Comment: It depends on the library. Some, like jOOQ, support properly parameterized queries and return types. Some do not. I'm not sure if JPA does, in this case. So if your library doesn't allow you to write this in a type-safe way, a cast is indeed the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't another good way to solve this. You can't do an `instanceof` check because of the type erasure and the signature of `Criteria#list()` uses a raw type.
The only thing you could do is to run an `instanceof` check on every item in the resulting list but it's reasonable to trust the framework to only return objects that match your criteria in this case. Also checking every item will still not get rid of the `unchecked` warning.
So `@SuppressWarnings` is the right thing to do here.

Answer (score 0):

Please think for 5 minutes and tell me, is the following code type safe?

```
public class Stackoverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stackoverflow sof = new Stackoverflow();
        Cage cage = sof.getCage();
        // are the dogs safe???????
        List<Dog> dogs = (List<Dog>) cage.list();
    }
    public Cage getCage() {
        List cage = new ArrayList<>();
        cage.add(new Lion());
        cage.add(new Dog());
        return new Cage(cage);
    }

    class Cage {
        List cage;
        public Cage(List cage) {
            this.cage = cage;
        }
        public List list() {
            return cage;
        }
    }

    class Animal {
        public void eat() {}
    }
    class Lion extends Animal {
        public void eat() {
            System.out.println("eat the animals around");
        }
    }
    class Dog extends Animal {
        public void eat() {
            System.out.println("eat bones");
        }
    }
}
```

5 minutes later.

Dogs are not safe because of lions in cages.

Because the original type (`List`) is used, the generic feature is lost, and it cannot be checked at compile time. The error will be left in the code and leaked at runtime (that is, the dog was eaten by a lion)

When you can ensure that the data in your collection is safe, then you can use `@SupressWarnings` to ignore compile-time checks.

For example, if your `getCage` method is written like this, you can guarantee type safety

```
public Cage getCage() {
    List cage = new ArrayList<>();
    cage.add(new Dog()); // Here, instead of putting a lion in a cage, a dog is put in a cage
    cage.add(new Dog());
    return new Cage(cage);
}
```

For your code, I think it is safe. just use `@SupressWarnings` to ignore compile-time checks.

This should be guaranteed for the `createCriteria(getPersistentClass())` method.
The premise is that the return value of `getPersistentClass()` is `HealthEntity.class`